# Join was successful however resulting table has no rows, create table with now rows?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to spatially join a layer of points to a polygon layer using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4. Both layers have the same projection system.

I am getting an error message:

> The join was successful however the resulting table has no rows,
>   create table with now rows?

Then an empty layer is created, that has the correct column headings, but no rows.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: If you run a "Select by Location" do you get any results and intersecting points/polygons?

Comment: Your error message including "now rows" sounds like it may not have been copied accurately.  In any event can you provide more details about where your points lie in relation to the polygons, and the precise parameter values that you are supplying to any tool(s) that you use, please?